# How to remove empty lines from visually selected block?

Tags: key-bindings

I am using following mapping. The command works fine but when I open a new file, all the empty lines are highlighted. Could you please check my mapping?

```
vnoremap <leader>n :g/^$/d<CR><Esc>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want your substitution to impact `hlsearch`, you can execute it within a function, which effectively creates a kind of bubble (a closure) around the commands in its body:

```
function! Trim() range
    execute a:firstline .. ',' .. a:lastline .. 'g/^$/d'
endfunction
xnoremap <leader>n :call Trim()<CR>
```

Note that, while this solution is slightly more involved than the other one, it has the advantage of leaving the search register completely untouched: you don't get the unwanted `^$` but you don't get random garbage either, which is a lot cleaner and makes the search register actually reusable.

See `:help function-range`.

Comment: this works quite well, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Your command is good but it set the search register `/` to `^$` that highlight the empty lines if `hlsearch` is set.

To avoid that you could do:

```
vnoremap <leader>n :g/^$/d<CR>:let @/='h6d4o9kz'<CR><Esc>
```

Comment: "search *register*".

Comment: @romainl Thanks :-)

Comment: Thank you @VivianDeSmedt, used romainl  solution given it seems more robust.

Comment: Indeed I like the fact that it doesn't affect the search register (`/`). I have also learned something :-)